# Opening a VS2008 Project/Solution and I get this error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution-explorer

I get the following error when I double click the SLN file.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Why do I get this error message?

When I click on OK (in the MessageBox), I see that Project is Unavailable in Visual Studio Solution Explorer. Can someone explain this behaviour?

This happens only for the solution which I have pulled out of Source Control. If I create a project/solution in the same machine or copy it from a different machine, they open fine.

Is it due to the Source Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention it only happens when opening from source control. You could try re-installing your source control plugin.

Also, after the error, check the output window (View->Output) for any more detailed error messages. (Make sure you change the "Show output from" combo box and check all the available sources)

It might also be worth deleting the .suo file from the solution directory. This file contains user settings and state and can sometimes be corrupted and cause errors.

Comment: Apologies if my writing was not clear. It is not about when opening from Source Control. It happens for Projects which are **pulled** out of source control. As in, when you have a project which is part of Source Control, you "Get the Latest Version", then you copy it over to another machine of another developer... **then** we get the error message.

Comment: @Kanini. If you are using a VS plugin that knows about your source control VS will tag all of your projects and solutions with an extra bit of code so it knows what source control plugin to load when the solution is next opened - even if it is on a different machine. If you are only getting this error when you are opening solutions that have come from source control it is likely that its the source control plugin that is causing the error when it is loaded. Of course if no such plugin is installed then that's not it. Check Tools->Options->SourceControl->CurrentPlugin and see what are available